# Using timestampdiff and getting the previous log of particular user

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to get the difference between 2 datetime where datetime 1 is `now()` and datetime 2 is the previous log of particular user.

I am looking for something like this

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(NOW(), Previous_Log_of_User)
```

So, if for example I have 2 users and I have this `teller_log` table

name           timestamp                         action              duration

user1           2015-09-09 15:00:40         login               00:00:00

user1           2015-09-09 15:00:45         increment     00:00:05

user1           2015-09-09 15:00:52         increment     00:00:07

user2           2015-09-09 15:00:52         login               00:00:00

user1           2015-09-09 15:00:55`        increment     00:00:03

user2           2015-09-09 15:00:58`        increment     00:00:06

user1           2015-09-09 15:01:00`        logout           00:00:02

user2           2015-09-09 15:01:00`        logout           00:00:02

As you can see in the example above I have 2 users and the starting point is if the user `logs in`, if the users action is increment I will calculate the time  between `login` and the `increment` action, then if the users action is increment again we will now calculate the duration between previous increment and the increment now and so on and so forth until the user logs out which will mark the end.

One of the problems that I encounter here is because the table is not consistent, I can't rely on user_id alone to get the previous log of particular user. There are cases that the previous id of user1 is an id of user2.

**Question:**

Is there an easy way to do this beside using timedifference? Or any other approach that I can take? I'm spending ample amount of time here.

**Edit:**

I am using `MySQL` and `VB.NET`.

My database is like this

[image]

Our focus here is the `teller_log` table which logs any actions of the `teller_info`, and this `teller_info` table gets the name of the user in `user_info` table by means of `teller_id` field both in `user_info` and `teller_info`.

Then we can create a log with combined information from `user_info` and `teller_info` by means of `user_id` field in `user_info` table.

**What I am trying to achieve** is

1. By means of this query I can easily get the duration of all logs. (For checking purposes)This means that the query should not have `WHERE`, though am not sure?
2. I want to get the duration of the latest log  according to time, which means that if user1 increments then it will create a log, and in that log I will specify the duration.

Comment: I am confused by this `There are cases that the previous id of user1 is an id of user2` arent the IDs unique?  An example of the problem would be helpful.  Item6 for instance correctly uses the previous user2 time not the previous entry (user1).  Also are you looking for a SQL/SP solution or app code?

Comment: @Plutonix, sorry. I forgot to say that it is `JOINED`and that `name = unique id of user_info` that example is `log_info` and it has also a unique id (I forgot to add it in the example above).

Comment: You are asking this?  "How can I add another column; it should contain the elapsed time for the user from the previous action."

Comment: @RickJames yes, exactly. I am sorry if I can't explain it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just `user1`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MAX(timestamp), NOW()) AS "Hours since last action"
    FROM tbl
    WHERE name = 'user1';
```

Minutes since each user did something:

```
SELECT  name,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(timestamp), NOW()) AS "Minutes since last action"
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY name;
```

If you want to know *what* action occurred last, that gets more complex.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I appreciate this but I am having a hard time on applying this to my database. Please see my updated question if you have time.

Comment: After thorough study and adjusting of my code I found out that this small query really works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your question reads a little ambiguously. I have interpreted this as one of two ways "For each action, I want to know the elapsed time between it and "now", or "For each action, I want to know the elapsed time since the previous action".

Based on the above interpretations, try the following (here's the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dbc4/25))

```
select name, actionTimestamp, actionName, prevTimestamp
  , TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, actionTimestamp, NOW()) as elapsedTimeSinceAction
  , TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, prevTimestamp, actionTimestamp) as timeBetweenActions
FROM
(select *, (SELECT MAX(log2.actionTimestamp) 
            FROM UserLog log2 
            WHERE log2.name = log1.name AND log2.actionTimestamp < log1.actionTimestamp) as prevTimestamp
 FROM UserLog log1
) a
ORDER BY name, actionTimestamp DESC, prevTimestamp DESC;
```

If I misinterpreted your question, please update the question with example input and expected output.

To address the second question (here's [another SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cd7a/2)):

```
/* Gets the most recent action for each user.
Note that if the same user performs multiple actions with the exact same timestamp,
multiple records may be returned for that user. */
select log2.name, log2.actionName, log2.actionTimestamp
  , TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, log2.actionTimestamp, NOW()) as elapsedTimeSinceAction 
FROM
(SELECT name, MAX(actionTimestamp) actionTimestamp FROM UserLog GROUP BY name) latestUserTimestamp
JOIN UserLog log2 ON log2.name = latestUserTimestamp.name
     AND log2.actionTimestamp = latestUserTimestamp.actionTimestamp;

/* Gets the most recent action for the user that performed the most recent 
action in the system.
Note that if two (or more) users perform an action with the exact same timestamp,
multiple users will be returned. */
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, actionTimestamp, NOW()) as elapsedTimeSinceAction
FROM UserLog
WHERE actionTimestamp = (SELECT MAX(actionTimestamp) FROM UserLog);
```

Comment: sorry if my question is unclear before. I managed to add more information. By the way, yes! the query that you made is very good, it solves the # 1, how can I modify it to solve # 2 of what I am trying to achieve? Right now I'm studying your query so I can fit it in my database. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are many approachs to do that. If you do not want to make all the calculations within the SQL statement, you could simply query all the data in a datatable and then do something like this:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("name")
    dt.Columns.Add("timestamp")
    dt.Columns.Add("action")
    dt.Columns.Add("duration")
    dt.Rows.Add("user1", "2015-09-09 15:00:40", "login", "00:00:00")
    dt.Rows.Add("user1", "2015-09-09 15:00:45", "increment", "00:00:05")
    dt.Rows.Add("user1", "2015-09-09 15:00:52", "increment", "00:00:07")
    dt.Rows.Add("user2", "2015-09-09 15:00:52", "login", "00:00:00")
    dt.Rows.Add("user1", "2015-09-09 15:00:55", "increment", "00:00:03")
    dt.Rows.Add("user2", "2015-09-09 15:00:58", "increment", "00:00:06")
    dt.Rows.Add("user1", "2015-09-09 15:01:00", "logout", "00:00:02")
    dt.Rows.Add("user2", "2015-09-09 15:01:00", "logout", "00:00:02")

    dt.AcceptChanges()

    Dim distinctDT As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "name")
    Dim name As String = ""
    Dim action As String = ""
    Dim previousAction As String = ""
    Dim initialDate As DateTime = Now
    Dim finalDate As DateTime = Now

    For j As Integer = 0 To distinctDT.Rows.Count - 1
        name = distinctDT.Rows(j)("name")
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            If name = dt.Rows(i)("name") Then
                action = dt.Rows(i)("action")
                If action = "login" Then
                    initialDate = CDate(dt.Rows(i)("timestamp"))
                    previousAction = action
                ElseIf action = "logout" Then
                    previousAction = action
                    finalDate = CDate(dt.Rows(i)("timestamp"))
                End If
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox(name & " => " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, initialDate, finalDate), vbInformation)
    Next
```

I am not sure if i understood correctly but you need only the actions: login and logout to calculate the duration and besides that, you have to make some minor modifications to the code shown to take account of situations where you do not have an action login before the logout or do not have the logout action during the log file you have. This is the reason i considered the variable previousAction even without using it in the code above.

I hope i could help in something.